# How to get the last n items in a PHP array as another array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to I get an array of the last n items of another array in PHP?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`$n` is equal to the number of items you want off the end.

```
$arr = array_slice($old_arr, -$n);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$arr = array_slice($old_arr, -$n, $n, true);
```

If the array indices are meaningful to you, remember that `array_slice` will reset and reorder the numeric array indices. You need the `preserve_keys` flag (4th parameter) set to **true** to avoid this.