# Array with only 10 most recent values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with multiple elements. I want to keep only the 10 most recent values. So I am reversing the array in a loop, checking if the element is within the first 10 range and if not, I unset the element from the array.

Only problem is that the unset does not work. I am using the key to unset the element, but somehow this does not work. The array keeps on growing. Any ideas?

```
$currentitem = rand(0,100);

$lastproducts = unserialize($_COOKIE['lastproducts']);
$count = 0;

foreach(array_reverse($lastproducts) as $key => $lastproduct) {

    if ($count <= 10) {
        echo "item[$key]: $lastproduct <BR>";       
    }

    else {
        echo "Too many elements. Unsetting item[$key] with value $lastproduct <BR>";
        unset($lastproducts[$key]);
    }

    $count = $count + 1;

}

array_push($lastproducts, $currentitem);

setcookie('lastproducts', serialize($lastproducts), time()+3600);
```

Comment: sidenote: mind marking all your other questions as solved, the ones that have given you solutions? Otherwise, people will think they're not solved and may post more answers.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468912/php-get-the-last-3-elements-of-an-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591867/how-to-get-the-last-n-items-in-a-php-array-as-another-array

Comment: @SougataBose I was going to suggest exactly the same thing. Why not use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) or [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)? That way there is no need to loop through the reversing array which will make the process more convenient and efficient.

Comment: why do you need to call `array_reverse()` ? why not simply using `count()`, `array_shift()` and `array_push` ?

Comment: How do I mark a question as being solved? I will look into the array_slice and array_splice possibilities. But my question about the unset still remains?

Comment: You mean `unset` doesn't remove the current element?

Comment: If you want to remove the current element using `unset`, add reference operator `&` before the `$lastproduct` in the `foreach` declaration, so the code looks like `foreach(array_reverse($lastproducts) as $key => &$lastproduct) {` and once you're done with this, replace `unset($lastproducts[$key]);` with `unset($lastproduct);`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use array_slice ( http://php.net/array_slice ) perhaps like:

```
$lastproducts = unserialize($_COOKIE['lastproducts']);
// add on the end ...
$lastproducts[] = $newproduct;
// start at -10 from the end, give me 10 at most 
$lastproducts = array_slice($lastproducts, -10); 
// ....
```

Comment: `array_slice($lastproducts, -10); ` is alone enough. You don't need to specify `length` parameter. Edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to select last 10 is:

```
$selection = array();
foreach(array_reverse($lastproducts) as $key => $lastproduct) {
  $selection[$key] = $lastproduct;
  if (count($selection)>=10) break;
}
```

Finally, `$selection` will have last 10 (or less) products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_splice($input, $offset)` function for this purpose.

```
$last_items_count = 10;
if(count($lastproducts) >= $last_items_count) {
    $lastproducts = array_splice($lastproducts, count($lastproducts) - $last_items_count);
}

var_dump($lastproducts);
```

I hope this code helps.

For more information, here is the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Answer (score 0):

Works great using array_splice and array_slice, thanks! :)

```
$lastproducts = unserialize($_COOKIE['lastproducts']);

// remove this product from array
$lastproducts = array_diff($lastproducts, array($productid));

// insert product on first position in array
array_splice($lastproducts, 0, 0, $productid);

// keep only first 15 products of array
$lastproducts = array_slice($lastproducts, 0, 15);
```