# Sorting JSON array from last to first by date in PHP, using a variable

Tags: php, json, api

thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I'm working on something that's dynamic and has data added daily, but is sorted from first to last in the JSON file, when I want to go from last (most recent) to first.

What I did was get the total number of entries by simply using

```
$total = $response['result']['total'];
```

Which gives me the total, 84. If I want the next last in the sequence, I just go:

```
 echo $total - 1
```

Which gives me 83.

This is where the problem comes in

I'm arranging my data like this:

```
echo $reo[0]['previous_day_doses_administered'];
```

Where the [0] is, I want $total - 1

However, I'm not sure how to get it, as it would be

```
   $reo[$response['result']['total']]['previous_day_doses_administered'];
```

which is definitely wrong. I'm wondering how to convert the $total to an integer, and have it no longer associated with the JSON array. I'm sorry if this is confusing! I just want to have the last 10 entries show up, instead of the first 10.

So, that's basically it. I've tried a couple things I found on here, but it screwed everything up. The API updates daily. If you want the link, let me know.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and sorry that I'm being so confusing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last n items in a PHP array as another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591867/how-to-get-the-last-n-items-in-a-php-array-as-another-array)

Comment: Getting the last 10 items of an array can be pretty simple with built-in functions (consult the duplicate). If you want them from newest to oldest, you just need to [reverse the order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse) after you've extracted them.

Comment: I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do not add "Solved" to your title, and edit your question with the answer. There is a section below this specifically for Answers, so please remove that content from your question and post it below.