# Add last 3 products to compare -> Laravel -PHP

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session, store

I want to get last three products from session in my comaparison page
here is my code

```
class CompareController extends Controller 
{     
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (App::isLocale('en')) {
            $language_id =  1;
        }else{
            $language_id =  4;
        }
       
        $data =   $request->products_id;
        $arr = Session::get('success');
        if( in_array( $data, $arr , TRUE )){
            return  $arr ;
        }else{
            Session::push('success',$data);
        }
    
        if(count($arr) > 3){
            array_shift($arr);
         }
         $product = DB::table('products')
                ->leftJoin('products_description','products_description.products_id','=','products.products_id')
                ->leftJoin('products_description','products_description.products_id','=','products.products_id')
                ->where('products_description.language_id','=', $language_id)
                ->whereIn('products.products_id',  $arr   )
                ->get();
    
        return view("website.layout.compare",compact('product'));
    }
    public function addToCompare(Request $request){
        
    }
   
}
```

Comment: here is my ajax code

Comment: $(document).on('click','.compare',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-shopping-cart');
                $(this).children('.fa').addClass('fa-spinner');
                var products_id = $(this).children('.fa').attr('data-prod_id');
                var url = '{{ url("/addToCompare") }}';
                var that = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data:{'products_id':products_id},
                    cache: true,
                    async: false,

Comment: Nobody can read that in a comment, post it to the question using the Edit link under the question

Comment: Great Gobs of white space do nat make code easier to read!!! Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are you asking "*how to get the last 3 elements of an array*"?  Because searching for that exact phrase turns up many answers, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468912/php-get-the-last-3-elements-of-an-associative-array-while-preserving-the-keys, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591867/how-to-get-the-last-n-items-in-a-php-array-as-another-array, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last n items in a PHP array as another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591867/how-to-get-the-last-n-items-in-a-php-array-as-another-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Example :

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

For your question :

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5]; // replace $arr with Session::get('success')

$output = array_slice($arr, -3,3)); // returns [3,4,5]
```